# d3.js radar chart with images provided in data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

i'm trying to use the D3.js library together with the block of nbremer. My problem is that the image I provide in the index.html ( "Picture1.png" for example ) is not displayed on the axis of the radar chart. At the momement I'm using a dummy image as you can see in radarchart.js But I want to use the image that is provided in the data in the index.html The img property to be exact.

Can anyone give me an idea / push in the right direction?
Thank you in advanced!

Here is a jsfiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5qLmv9j/1/)

```
//Append the icon
axis.append("svg:image")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .style("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle") //  
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://dummyimage.com/60x60/000/ffffff.png")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return rScale(maxValue * cfg.labelFactor) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return rScale(maxValue * cfg.labelFactor) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("width", 60)
    .attr("height", 60);
```

This is where I load the dummy image.

[Here is an example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLOLr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide an image based on the `data` array we'll have to filter the data, once the axes are using a different data array (called `allAxis`, and also based on `data`). Of course, a cleaner solution would be simply pushing the images together into `allAxis`, but let's see how to link them using `data`.

This is the snippet with the relevant modification:

```
 axis.append("svg:image")
     .attr("xlink:href", function(d){
          var image = data[0].filter(function(e) {
              return e.axis == d;
          });
          return image[0].img
     })
```

Here, for every value in `axis`, we filter the `data` array (I'm using `data[0]` since your data array is repetitive) accordingly.

Notice that, once we are returning the value for `img` key, the key has to contain *the entire path* for that image (if it is in a different directory). Alternatively, you can do:

```
return "http://www.somewebsite.com/" + image[0].img
```

If the `img` key contains only the name of the file (and, again, if the file is in another directory/domain).

Here is your fiddle with different images for each axis: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/33k6m7tj/

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I now understand what I did wrong.